# Hide navigationBar and toolbar in view using UIGestureRecognizer, which contains UIWebView and UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating a UIViewController with UIImageView, 2xUIWebView.
[image]

I'm trying to hide UINavigationBar and UIToolBar with UITapGestureRecognizer, It's no problem, but when i added in ViewController UIWebView it stop works. In "UIWebView youtube player" - I Have code which plays video from youtube. When I'm touching in "white area" or UIImageView- gesture recognizer works, but when I'm touching UIWebView - nothing happens. Help me please fix it. Thank you

Comment: Please provide more info. To which object is gesture recognizer attached to? Also, UIWebView documentation warns about using it as UIScrollView subview because touch events might weird out. Similar thing might be happening in this case also because UIWebView does not like when other objects are interfering with its touch events.

Answer (score 0):

If you are add gesture recognizer to the parent view than you are doing it wrong. You should attach it to the webView instead.

```
[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

instead of

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView consists of some subviews, and the subviews have already add some gesture recognizers, so if you just add gesture recognizer to UIWebView, it will not be processed, because the deeper UIView in the view tree will handle the gesture first. To allow both the new added gesture recognizer and the built-in gesture recognizer processed simultaneously, you should adopt the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol to allow this.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

yourTapRecognizer.delegate = self; //add this line with you UIGestureRecognizer alloc/init
```

for some detail information see this blog: [How to Add Custom Process to UIWebview Tap Gestures](http://www.wubaoli.me/?p=52)